# lazarus DBGrid lookup field (no creation)

Tags: lazarus

I have been using Lazarus 2.x with Firebird 3 (via flamerobin) and i have got two tables: appeals with a foreign key (promoter_id) and promoter (id,fullname).

I would like to create a lookup field for DBGrid with field properties from dataset appeals and lookup fields from dataset promoter.

Thus i have got the following script:

```
interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, DBGrids,Unit3,DB;

type

  { TForm5 }

  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure showgrid;
    procedure showlookup;
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm5 }

procedure TForm5.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 //showlookup;
 showgrid;
 showlookup;
end;

procedure TForm5.showgrid;
begin

 appeals.SQLQuery2.Close;
 appeals.SQLQuery2.SQL.Text:='select * from appeals where datediff(day,cast(''Now'' as date),cast(date_judgement as date))<5 and date_court IS NOT NULL';

 appeals.DBConnection.Connected:=True;
 appeals.SQLTransaction1.Active:=True;
 //appeals.SQLQuery2.Open;

 //appeals.DataSource1.DataSet:=appeals.SQLQuery2;
 //DBGrid1.DataSource:=appeals.DataSource1;

 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[1].Width:=120;
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[0].Visible:=false;
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[1].Title.Caption:='Name';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[2].Title.Caption:='Date Entry';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[3].Title.Caption:='Date Suspension';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[4].Title.Caption:='Date Examination';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[5].Title.Caption:='Date Final';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[6].Title.Caption:='Promoter';

end;

procedure TForm5.showlookup;
begin

 appeals.SQLQuery4.Close;
 appeals.SQLQuery4.SQL.Text:='select id,fullname from promoter';
 //appeals.SQLQuery4.Open;

 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[6].Field.FieldName:='promoter_id';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[6].Field.FieldKind:=fkLookup;
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[6].Field.KeyFields:='promoter_id';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[6].Field.LookupDataSet:= appeals.SQLQuery4;
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[6].Field.LookupKeyFields:='id';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[6].Field.LookupResultField:='fullname';
 DBGrid1.Columns.Items[6].Field.DataSet:=appeals.SQLQuery2;

 appeals.SQLQuery4.Open;
 appeals.SQLQuery2.Open;

 appeals.DataSource1.DataSet:=appeals.SQLQuery2;
 DBGrid1.DataSource:=appeals.DataSource1;
end;

end.
```

As soon as i run it, i receive the following error (attached) or in text description **ElistError:ListIndex (1) out of bounds**.

[image]

Additionally I have played with my code by running and opening first the queries but no lookupfield is shown in Promoter column grid (only numbers and no text description). Unfortunately there is no bibliography or code examples of creating lookup fields or computed in Lazarus IDE.

Any help would be convenient to me!

Regards

Comment: Btw, please do not delete a q after it has been answered, even if your interest has moved on to something else.  The whole point of SO is that it is a repository of answered questions for the benefit and information of future readers, not just the person who asked the q.

Comment: OK i did not know that. Sorry, I was a little frustrated as i have lost some marks.

Comment: I am not going to spend time writing an answer to this.  As I told in you in another q, you are going about this the wrong way.  The correct way is to create the lookup field in the dataset which feeds the grid **before** you open the dataset.  If you do that using the Fields editor in the IDE, you will then be able to create a suitable column for it in the DBGrid using the Columns editor in the IDE.  It should take you about 2 minutes in total, maybe less.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just found some examples of how to create dummy fields during run time, but none of them actually worked. Your idea was the best regarding field editor.